# PROLOG - clause returns true for constants, but won't find solution for variable?

Tags: prolog, logic, prolog-dif

After many years of abstinence of the PROLOG programming language, I'm trying to get into it again.
And promptly there, something confused me.

(I am using SWI prolog 6.4.1. on windows)

Consider the following defined:

```
father(jack, clara).
father(jack, sophie).

mother(angela,clara).
mother(angela,sophie).

parent(A, B) :- father(A, B).
parent(A, B) :- mother(A, B).

sibling( A, B ) :-
    A \= B,
    parent(P, A),
    parent(P, B).
```

Now, if I "ask" the interpreter:
*sibling(clara, sophie).*

*true* is the answer.

But if I try to get the siblings of e.g. clara:
*sibling(clara, X).*

The answer is just *false*.
Just as
*findall( X, sibling(clara, X ), L ).*

returns an empty list.

Why?

Comment: `\=` is to be read as "can't be unified with", **not** as "isn't". Then there's no misreading any statement which uses it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To prove `sibling(clara, X)`, you first need to prove `clara \= x`. But that doesn't work because it reduces to `\+ clara = X`, were `\+` is the infamous [negation as failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_as_failure): Prolog tries to prove `clara = X`, which succeeds, and concludes that `clara \= X` must therefore be false.

You should either reorder your program to do the `\=` check last instead of first, or use `dif(clara, X)`.

Comment: That was quick, I'll try that out right away :-)
Interesting - the order of statements matters? I regarded the comma as AND operator.

Comment: @dont ask, The order of statements is very important in Prolog. The comma is in fact and AND operator (and the ; is an OR operator by the way). Because of that order some predicates may not even end. You may look at the unification algorithm to understand why it is important. Also, have a look at the OR operator. It will help to understand.

Comment: Oh, and I was writing a clause multiple times with different "bodies" to get an OR effect. 10 years ago I wrote stuff like tree search algorithms in PROLOG, I wonder how I got by knowing so little back then, or if I really have forgotten so much :-D
Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: @dontask: yes, order of statements matters, because Prolog uses an incomplete inference algorithm.